# Merge 2 JS Arrays of Objects by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

***Problem***

I have two Javascript arrays of objects I need to merge.  I need to merge by matching the unique values of a single key:value pair that are contained in each array.  The keys for the values I want to merge based on are different

I want to add the key: value pairs from Array 2 to the correct object in Array 1 based on the matching unique value.  The values for array1.user and array2._id are the values that I need to match by.

***Arrays***

```
const array1 = [ { _id: 5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d },
  { _id: 5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e } ]

const array2 = users [ { _id: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d,
    info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' } },
  { _id: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e,
    info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } } ]
```

***What I've tried***

I've tried using lodash's _.map and _.extend function like so but I'm new to lodash and it's not giving me the proper output

```
  const mergedArray = _.map(array1, function(item){
    return _.extend(item, _.find(array2, {_id: item.user}));
  });
```

***Result***

```
mergedArray [ { _id: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d,
    info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' } },
  { _id: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e,
    info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } }]
```

***Desired Result***

```
const mergedArray = [ { _id: 5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d,
    info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' } } ,
  { _id: 5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee,
    user: 5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e, 
    info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } } ]
```

Comment: Why are they arrays? Is there a required sorting order? If not, you seem to have unique IDs, which makes the structure much more handy as an object where the `_id` is the key. Then you can easily look up by ID, and avoid all that iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two unordered objects with different keys but same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725142/merge-two-unordered-objects-with-different-keys-but-same-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

In case your mapping of arrays are in same sequence than you can avoid use of `find`

```js
const array1 = [ { _id: `5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff`,user: `5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d` },{ _id: `5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee`,user: `5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e` }]
const array2 =[ { _id: `5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d`,info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' } },{ _id: `5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e`,info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } } ]
    
const final = array1.map(e=> {
  const found = array2.find(({_id}) => e.user === _id)
  return {
    ...e,
    info : found.info
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: The two arrays I need to merge are actually being returned from MongoDB and for some reason any method I've tried doesn't work, even though the same method works perfectly for a javascript array.  Do you have any suggestions how to apply this solution to arrays returned from MongoDB?  I'm using Mongoose if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and build new object for the result.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ _id: '5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d' }, { _id: '5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee', user: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e' }],
    array2 = [{ _id: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d', info: { name: 'John', city: 'New York' } }, { _id: '5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e', info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } }],
    users = new Map(array2.map(({ _id, info }) => [_id, { info }])),
    merged = array1.map(o => ({ ...o, ...(users.get(o.user) || {}) }));

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The two arrays I need to merge are actually being returned from MongoDB and for some reason any method I've tried doesn't work, even though the same method works perfectly for a javascript array.  Do you have any suggestions how to apply this solution to arrays returned from MongoDB?  I'm using Mongoose if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to generate an object with keys, and later get the values directly using that generated object.  The key access is very fast.

```js
const array1 = [ { _id: "5c6c7132f9bf4bdab9c906ff",user: "5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d" },{ _id: "5c6ccd6d3a0dc4e4951c2bee",user: "5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e" } ];
const ids = array1.reduce((a, {user, _id}) => ({...a, [user]: _id}), {});
const array2 = [ { _id: "5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7d",info: { name:'John', city: 'New York' } },{ _id: "5c65d9438e4a834c8e85dd7e", info: { name: 'Paneer', city: 'San Fran' } } ];
    
array2.forEach(o => {
  o.user = o._id;
  o._id = ids[o._id];
});

console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```